# Batch: how create .bat with a batch escaping special chars

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Why it not works?
I want to create a .bat by a batch file, but i can't create a .bat file with variables insides.

Thanks!

```
rem echo off

echo @echo off > c:\temp\ping.bat

echo rem Test della perdita di pacchetti verso un indirizzo >> c:\temp\ping.bat

echo set data^=20^%date:~6,4^%_^%date:~3,2^%_^%date:~0,2^% >> c:\temp\ping.bat

echo set ora=^%time:~0,2^% >> c:\temp\ping.bat

echo set name^=ping-^%data^% >> c:\temp\ping.bat

echo @echo on >> c:\temp\ping.bat

set comando=ping -t %addr%

echo %comando% >> c:\temp\ping.bat
```

---

Thanks!!! I did it because I need to create a "ping.bat" to put in autorun on Windows starts, if required by program caller. I forgot to save output on txt and show it on standard output, how prova.bat can redirect output into ping.txt? Thanks

```
@echo off
(
    echo @echo off
    echo rem Test della perdita di pacchetti verso %addr% 
    echo set data=20%%date:~6,4%%_%%date:~3,2%%_%%date:~0,2%%
    echo set ora=%%time:~0,2%%
    echo set name=ping.txt
```

> echo %%data%% - %%Time:~0,5%% ^>> c:\temp\%name%

```
    echo @echo on
```

> echo ping -t %addr% ^>> c:\temp\%name%

```
    echo @exit /b
) > c:\temp\ping.bat
```

Comment: Whenever you want a literal percent sign, use `%%` rather than `^%`.  And it doesn't appear that you're ever defining `%addr%` in your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should create your file, but your code will not work!

```
@echo off
(
    echo @echo off
    echo rem Test della perdita di pacchetti verso un indirizzo 
    echo set data=20%%date:~6,4%%_%%date:~3,2%%_%%date:~0,2%%
    echo set ora=%%time:~0,2%%
    echo set filename=ping-%%data%%.txt
    echo ping -t %addr% ^>^> c:\temp\%%filename%%
) > c:\temp\ping.bat
```

You named your batch file `ping.bat` and then you try to call `ping -t %addr%`.
This will end up in an endless loop.

Btw. Why you don't use a simple batch function instead?

```
@echo off
set addr=10.0.0.1
call :ping %addr%
exit /b

:ping
set "data=20%date:~6,4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%"
set "ora=%time:~0,2%"
set "name=ping-%data%"
ping -t %1
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I need to create a "ping.bat" to put in autorun on Windows starts. I forgot to save output on txt and show it on standard output, how prova.bat can redirect output into ping.txt? Thanks `@echo off
(
    echo @echo off
    echo rem Test della perdita di pacchetti verso un indirizzo 
    echo set data=20%%date:~6,4%%_%%date:~3,2%%_%%date:~0,2%%
    echo set ora=%%time:~0,2%%
    echo set name=ping.txt
    echo %%data%% - %%Time:~0,5%% >> c:\temp\%name%
    echo @echo on 
    (echo ping -t %addr%) >> c:\temp\%name%
    echo exit /b
) > c:\temp\ping.bat`

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28300891/edit) your question and add the code there (otherwise it is not formatted in a way that is easy to read).